# Como contar os elementos de uma lista

Tags: python, array, python-3.x, lista

Tenho uma lista que armazena dados:

```
[(pizzas, 'COMIDA'), (1, 'QUANTIDADE'), (chocolate, 'SABOR'), (1, 'QUANTIDADE'), (catupiry, 'SABOR'), (1, 'QUANTIDADE'), (morango, 'SABOR')]
```

Gostaria de verificar o que está dentro da minha lista.

Exemplo: se tiver o token `COMIDA`, ou `Quantidade`, ou `SABOR`, ou ambos, gostaria que me retornasse a seguinte saída:

```
COMIDA = true ou a quantidade QUANTIDADE = true ou a quantidade SABOR = true ou a quantidade
```

Outra coisa, é possível também a partir do Token (Exemplo: `COMIDA`), me retornar 'pizzas', ou `SABOR` retornar `chocolate, morango, catupiry`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua lista python se chama um dicionario, e o formato esta 'invertido'

```
a = {"aaa":111, "bbb":222, "ccc":333}
```

isto é o formato de um dicionario em python ou seja sao pares {"chave":valor} o que apresentaste ai foi uma lista de tuples , mas geralmente se nao me engano estes tem tendencia a serem valores numericos.

pode tambem criar uma lista de objetos em python

```
class comida:  
def __init__(self, comidaTipo, quantidade, sabor):  
    self.comidaTipo= comidaTipo
    self.quantidade = quantidade
    self.sabor = sabor

# definiçao da lista
lista = []

# adiçao de um novo alimento
lista.append(comida('pizza',1,'chocolate'))
lista.append(comida('catupiry',8,'morango')) 


# print de true se o tipo de comida estiver la lista pode fazer return true tambem se for uma função -- pizza -- catupiry etc

for comida in lista:
     if "sua_variavel_filtro" == comida.comidaTipo:
       print("true")
```

Comment: Muito obrigado !

mas no caso do dicionário, como eu faria para filtrar os elementos que eu quero? exemplo verificar quais chaves estão presentes e o conteúdo delas relacionados??

Comment: as chaves tem de estar sempre presente o conteudo é que pode nao existir a sua chave é como uma forma de encontrar o conteudo o que podes fazer é um if dentro do for vou editar a resposta pra te ajudar mais um pouco